# Globalization of strings in MVC - JavaScript translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app, in which to translate I am storing all the text fields in a .resx file and then retrieving them with:

```
Resources.Resource.FirstName}
```

I have a JavaScript file which I need to do the same for two strings. I have checked Google and saw the JQuery.Globalization library (which doesn't seem to be available anymore) but that is way overkill for just two strings. I need to translate the two "Please wait..." strings in the following. How doo I do this easily?

```
$("#the_button").lockSubmit({
        submitText: "Please wait..."
    });

    $(".the_button").lockSubmit({
        submitText: "Please wait..."
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to define global js variabe in head section of html in layaout:

```
...
<script>
    var translation = {
        submitText: "@Resources.Resource.SubmitText"
    };
</script>
...
```

and then use this in js script

```
...
$("#the_button, .the_button").lockSubmit({        // you can use multiple selector here
    submitText: translation.submitText
});
...
```

You can also use html `data-*` attribute:

```
...
<button id="the_button" data-submit-text="@Resources.Resource.SubmitText" >Button</button>
```

and js file:

```
...
$("#the_button").lockSubmit({
    submitText: $("#the_button").attr("data-submit-text");
});
...
```